# Why is katakana /va/ normally written ヴァ rather than ヷ?

Tags: history, loanwords, katakana, obsolete-kana

Even though there is a katakana character ヷ, most of the time when I see something that is transcribed into Japanese as /va/, it is in the form ヴァ (say, for example, in the title of the anime series 革命機ヴァルヴレイヴ). Similarly, the forms ヸ, ヹ, and ヺ seem to be fairly rare too.

I can somewhat understand the rationale for using ヴィ and ヴェ for ヸ and ヹ given that ヰ and ヱ are almost obsolete in the contemporary written standard, but ワ is still a very common sound.

Is there a particular reason why the two-character form seems to be preferred over the single-character form?

Comment: I've never seen ヷ, ヸ, ヹ, or ヺ before.

Comment: ^ Me neither...  ヰ=ゐ ヱ=ゑ ヲ=を right? (How did you type ヷ, ヸ, ヹ, ヺ...??)

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%B4) states that ヷ, ヸ, ヹ, and ヺ were indeed used to represent va, vi, ve, and vo at some point, but these notations never became common.  But it does not state why.

Comment: The title is not accurate in that "va" is NOT normally written ヴァ.  It is much more often written バ.  There is no V sound in Japanese, so we could not really care less how "va" is transliterated. Both ヴァ and バ are pronounced バ anyway.

Comment: ヷヸヴヹヺ honestly seems so elegant for a "ヷ行" additional line. I wonder why they fell out of use even as V-containing loanwords *increased*, and the cumbersome notation became mainstream.

Comment: @user54609 I don't feel ヷヸヴヹヺ is very elegant.  ヴ feels out-of-place to me.  Also, ヰ and ヱ feel somehow incongruous with the "new" feel of the /v/ sound, because they feel so out-of-date.  (Of course, these are just my personal impressions.)

Comment: `because they feel so out-of-date` Not if they were reappropriated for loanwords rather than the equally ugly うぃうぇ getting used.

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you are asking, but ヷ, ヸ, ヹ, and ヺ are not just rare.  They are no longer in use, and as a result, not many contemporary speakers of Japanese have seen any of these letters (as some of the comments indicate).  If you are asking why they did not become popular, then I do not know if there is an explanation for it.

Answer (score 5):

I will hazard a guess here. If va was written ヷ then the entire v- line would probably have to be written with the w- line for consistency. I think the problem is that except for wa, the members of the w- line are strange. There is no wu. wo is only used for one word and we, wi are not used, meaning people are not as familiar with them.

People may have gotten annoyed by these factors and decided to use ヴ_ because it is more convenient for representing all of the v- sounds.